# Celular api7 problema con Android Studio

Tags: android, api, class

Trato de ejecutar mi app en mi celular pero me sale este mensaje:

> ```
> The following classes could not be instantiated:
> - android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
> - android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
> - android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
> ```

Mi celular al parecer tiene versión API 7. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: Prueba a invalidar cache y reiniciar. Tienes la opción en File -> Invalidate caches / restart

Comment: Puse la api17 para el mínimo y agregué Base. en styles.xml <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> y ya puedo ver la interfaz